# REST API - should server provide already-processed data or shall client process it itself

Tags: rest, date, client-server

I would like to ask one simple question about REST-approach.

So, here's the problem:
We are supposed to display the current date on the client-side, in this form:
DD.MM.YYYY HH:MM:SS

Now, the question is:
should server provide client a ready-to-display string containing, for example:
"04.07.2018 13:53:23"
OR
should server provide client some kind of general "Date" string, for example:
2018-07-02T09:22:02+02:00
and client should process it the way it needs to be displayed (DD.MM.YYYY HH:MM:SS format).

Will be grateful for answers answering which approach is better in this situation (concerning REST architectural design).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me exchanging dates in ISO 8601 makes much more sense. It's a well known and commonly used format that can be parsed by most of the dates manipulation tools. If you receive ISO formatted date you have much more flexibility on the client side. You can format it however you want without changing server code and use different formats in different places.

Comment: Thanks :) I think you are right, I was talking to some of my colleagues and this seems the best in our situation.

Answer (score 1):

Both aspects has their Pros and Cons

### Ready to display string

Pros

- Less client side processing(date time already formatted)

Cons

- Less flexibility on client side to display date-time in multiple formats
- Server processing is high(Centralized processing)

### General format(like Unix timestamp)

Pros

- More flexibility on client side(reusable for displaying required time format)
- Less server processing (De-centralized date/time formatting process )

Cons

- More client side processing(little bit of coding to display date/time,also might need external library to format)

#### As a suggestion,

If you are expecting sizable client base then better to go with option "General format" which also has required flexibility on client side to re-use and re-format as required.

If you are only expecting average client base and client application not that much complex to re-use/re-format time on multiple screen then "Ready to display" would be good.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use custom converters for ex: MessageBodyWriter in jersey

code:

```
package com.arun.java.customconverter;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
@Produces("text/shortdate")
public class ShortDateMessageBodyWriter implements MessageBodyWriter<Date> {

    @Override
    public boolean isWriteable(Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return Date.class.isAssignableFrom(type);
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(Date t, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType,
            MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders, OutputStream entityStream)
            throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        String shortdate= t.getDate()+"-"+t.getMonth()+"-"+t.getYear();
        entityStream.write(shortdate.getBytes()); 

    }

}
```